# Default alphabetical sort names of files

Tags: ruby, file, directory, dir

I've been experimenting with some Dir class and met some strange thing. As I read in ruby-doc array of strings will be sorted in alphabetical order. But while printing names, order is a bit different than alphabetical. Here's the code:

```
array = []
Dir.foreach(Dir.pwd){|f| array.push(f)}
puts array.sort!
```

And result:

```
File_class_test.rb
File_reading_test.rb
File_reading_test.rb~
Rule_them.txt
Shoes_test.rb
Summarize.rb
Text_analyzer.rb
file_rename.rb
file_rename.rb~
path.rb
path.rb~
test.txt
```

I also checked class of the f elements and it shows string.
So there's my question - am I doing something wrong with sorting/improper in code or just don't know about something?

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result is expected and case sensitive. If you do not care the case of those file names, just do the following:

```
Dir.foreach(Dir.pwd){|f| array.push(f.upcase)} # or downcase
```

Comment: Or use custom sort alternatively: `array.sort {|l,r| l.downcase <=> r.downcase}`